# Windows event codes for startup/shutdown lock/unlock

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I'm trying to build up a list of event Ids that can be used to determine when the machine has been shutdown, started up, locked and unlocked. So far, I've found 6 event IDs which seem to be best candidates but I was wondering if there was a better way of determining it.

Below is a list of event IDs I've found to be useful (1, 1074, 6005, 6006, 4800, 4801) from the 'Power-Troubleshooter', 'User32', 'EventLog' and 'Microsoft Windows security auditing' sources. These are from Windows 10 (v1511) and currently Windows 10 is my only target requirement as this is what all of the client machines run.

[image: List of event Ids]

Here is an example filter query I've built up which

```xml
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">
    <!-- Shutdown -->
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='User32'] and (EventID=1074) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime &gt;= '2017-11-28T00:00:00.0000000']]]</Select>

    <!-- Event Service Stop/Start -->
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='eventlog'] and (EventID=6005 or EventID=6006) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime &gt;= '2017-11-28T00:00:00.0000000']]]</Select>

    <!-- Startup -->
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter'] and (EventID=1) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime &gt;= '2017-11-28T00:00:00.0000000']]]</Select>

    <!-- Machine Lock/Unlock -->
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4800 or EventID=4801) and TimeCreated[@SystemTime &gt;= '2017-11-28T00:00:00.0000000']]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

I've deliberately split the sources out in the query and they can be joined together but this sacrifices readability IMO.

My question is whether there is a better group of event Ids or a better query that I can use? Are there event IDs that I'm missing or that I'm doubling up on?

> **Additional:**
> Sometimes (for instance if you're in a managed domain), you may need to enable the events for logging on and off via the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit). You can do this by following the below steps:
>
> 1. Open the `Task Manager` then `File` > `Run new task`.
> 2. Type `gpedit.msc` and check `Create this task with administrative privileges.`) and click OK.
> 3. In the Local Group Policy Editor, go to `Computer Configuration` > `Windows Settings` > `Security Settings` > `Advanced Audit Policy Configuration` > `System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object` > `Logon/Logoff`.
> 4. In the side panel, ensure the following categories have been set to `Success and Failure`. If they're not, double-click and enable them:
>
>    - `Audit Other Login/Logoff Events` (Success and Failure)
>    - `Audit Logon` (Success and Failure)
>    - `Audit Logoff` (Success and Failure)

Comment: I wonder if and how many of these will be version-specific. You might have to zero in on a version or family or something.

Comment: @ToddWilcox These are from Windows 10 (v1511) but there doesn't appear to be a generic catch-all log source for these types of events and I do appear to be doubling up (such as startup and event service start).

Comment: I hope/expect that at least Server 2016 may have the same or at least overlapping event IDs with Windows 10, but maybe not.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I think perhaps I've posted my question to the wrong place and should possibly put it on SuperUser or _maybe_ SO. Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily. I was mainly leading towards you might want to specify the OS that you're looking for the event IDs for, since it wasn't clear in the question. But if you're looking to monitor even logs of client machines on a business network then you're definitely in the right place.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The requirement is to create a monitor which can poll the logs on client machines (all Windows 10). Currently I have a 95% hit rate and can use them to more or less build up a picture of activity but the amount of duplication is somewhat annoying. For example if a system crashes then the system doesn't shut down, and as such there may be two consecutive 6006 events (event service start). I'm resigned to accepting those as inevitable though, but the event service stop + system shutdown is effectively duplication.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Refering to your request about starting and shutdown event IDs, I made the list below based on a Windows 10 machine. The main point is that depending on the shutdown action (planned reboot, planned shutdown, unexpected shutdown or LSASS process crash), the generated events will be differents:

> - 1074   The process Explorer.EXE has initiated the shutdown of computer     on behalf of user  for the following
>     reason: Other    (Unplanned)
> - 6006   The Event log service was stopped.
> - 109    The kernel power manager has initiated a shutdown transition.
> - 13 The operating system is shutting down at system time ‎
> - 20 The last shutdown's success status was true. The last boot's success status was true.
> - 12 The operating system started at system time
> - 6005   The Event log service was started.
> - 6013   The system uptime is 10 seconds.

To make a clear **overview** on those different shutdown actions, I made the following table. Hope it will help.

[image: shutdown events]

Comment: Thank you for this list! There are several in here that I've looked at previously but appear to be 'doubling up' on existing events. I haven't looked into the Kernel-* events for the same reason but using the list provided should help give a much clearer indication of client machine status. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if people are leaving their PCs in 'sleep' mode overnight, for example, the following event IDs garnered from Windows 11 will be of use:

- 42 The system is entering sleep.
- 107 The system has returned from sleep.

HTH somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I did a workup on your XML, way better than my old XML but we have a few different events so this is a merged version as I use mine to turn a power strip on and off (http://dbugslife.blogspot.com/2020/08/ScreenSaverPowerStrip.html) but its all remarked so you can weed for events you want to look for.

=== TURN OFF ===

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">
    <!-- Power Entering Sleep Mode -->
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power'] and (EventID=42)]]</Select>

    <!-- Shutdown/Reboot -->
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='User32'] and (EventID=1074)]]</Select>

    <!-- Event Log Service Stop -->
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='eventlog'] and (EventID=6006)]]</Select>

    <!-- Screensaver Invoked -->
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4802)]]</Select>

    <!-- Machine Lock -->
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4800)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

=== TURN ON ===

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">

    <!-- Power Resume from Sleep Mode -->
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power'] and (EventID=107)]]</Select>

    <!-- Event Log Service Start -->
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='eventlog'] and (EventID=6005)]]</Select>

    <!-- Returned from Low Power State-->
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter'] and (EventID=1)]]</Select>

    <!-- Screensaver Dismissed -->
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4803)]]</Select>

    <!-- Machine Lock/Unlock -->
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4801)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```