# Windows Event Viewer Not Showing Recent Events

Tags: windows, windows-11, event-log, lock-unlock

I've just created a custom view on Windows 11 using the following query, obtained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/885601/windows-event-codes-for-startup-shutdown-lock-unlock), and I have just unlocked my machine, yet the most recent unlock event is from `02-28T06:55`. What gives?

```xml
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power'] and (EventID=42)]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power'] and (EventID=107)]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='eventlog'] and (EventID=6006)]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='eventlog'] and (EventID=6005)]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='User32'] and (EventID=1074)]]</Select>
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4802)]]</Select>
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4803)]]</Select>
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter'] and (EventID=1)]]</Select>
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4800)]]</Select>
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and (EventID=4801)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your log size and the behavior once log is full.
You see those settings on event log's properties window